# Android: How to implement Google Sign in without Play Services

Tags: android

How to implement google sign-in in android without play services? Is it possible to do so with Android key, so I don't have to open a web view?

Is there official docs from google about this?

Comment: not possible in android device without google play service

Comment: did you try it ? @Ilya_Gazman

Comment: @Radhe I am implementing google drive now. I will make it public when I done.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth#register_your_app)

It allows you to work with google rest API, and you can use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) for sign in.

There used to be a good [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android#import) about **AccountManager**, but they been deprecated in favor of [Intet.newChooseAccountIntent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker#public-method-summary) provided by play services. But not that the code is not deprecated is just google who pushes to use play-services. There are other apps that work with **AccountManager** like Facebook and YouTube so they can't deprecate it.